# Why Gradient Descent Runs Away from Possible Solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-flows

I am trying to solve a multivariate optimization problem (actually trying to minimize a first order objective function) using gradient descent. The objective function is simple:

```
f(x, y) = 2*x + 3*y - 10
```

With each iteration (with a `step_size` of *0.001*), I am updating the x, y in a very classical text-book way:

```
x = x - (step_size * df/dx) 
y = y - (step_size * df/dy)
```

and with each iteration, when I calculate the value of objective function with updated `(x, y)`, it seems that the solution is running away negatively (with x and y being decreased negatively) from the 0 or root of the function.

What is this property? Is gradient descent thinking that its actually decreasing the objective function by decreasing the values of `(x, y)`, although the value of objective function also keeps decreasing into negative space.

Here is a trace of `f(x,y)` and `(x,y)` (50 iterations), with `(x,y)` being initialized at `(1,1)`. If you notice, `f(x,y)` is decreasing (and running away from solution 0) along with x and y being decreased too..:

```
> -5.012999999999153 [ 0.9979999999997204, 0.9970000000004688 ]
> -5.025999999998305 [ 0.9959999999994409, 0.9940000000009377 ]
> -5.038999999997458 [ 0.9939999999991613, 0.9910000000014065 ]
> -5.05199999999661 [ 0.9919999999988818, 0.9880000000018754 ]
> -5.064999999995763 [ 0.9899999999986022, 0.9850000000023442 ]
> -5.0779999999949155 [ 0.9879999999983227, 0.9820000000028131 ]
> -5.090999999994068 [ 0.9859999999980431, 0.9790000000032819 ]
> -5.103999999993221 [ 0.9839999999977636, 0.9760000000037508 ]
> -5.116999999992373 [ 0.981999999997484, 0.9730000000042196 ]
> -5.129999999991526 [ 0.9799999999972044, 0.9700000000046884 ]
> -5.142999999990678 [ 0.9779999999969249, 0.9670000000051573 ]
> -5.155999999989831 [ 0.9759999999966453, 0.9640000000056261 ]
> -5.1689999999889835 [ 0.9739999999963658, 0.961000000006095 ]
> -5.181999999988136 [ 0.9719999999960862, 0.9580000000065638 ]
> -5.194999999987289 [ 0.9699999999958067, 0.9550000000070327 ]
> -5.207999999986441 [ 0.9679999999955271, 0.9520000000075015 ]
> -5.220999999985594 [ 0.9659999999952475, 0.9490000000079704 ]
> -5.233999999984746 [ 0.963999999994968, 0.9460000000084392 ]
> -5.246999999983899 [ 0.9619999999946884, 0.943000000008908 ]
> -5.259999999983052 [ 0.9599999999944089, 0.9400000000093769 ]
> -5.272999999982204 [ 0.9579999999941293, 0.9370000000098457 ]
> -5.285999999981357 [ 0.9559999999938498, 0.9340000000103146 ]
> -5.298999999980509 [ 0.9539999999935702, 0.9310000000107834 ]
> -5.311999999979662 [ 0.9519999999932907, 0.9280000000112523 ]
> -5.3249999999788145 [ 0.9499999999930111, 0.9250000000117211 ]
> -5.337999999977967 [ 0.9479999999927315, 0.92200000001219 ]
> -5.35099999997712 [ 0.945999999992452, 0.9190000000126588 ]
> -5.363999999976272 [ 0.9439999999921724, 0.9160000000131276 ]
> -5.376999999975425 [ 0.9419999999918929, 0.9130000000135965 ]
> -5.389999999974577 [ 0.9399999999916133, 0.9100000000140653 ]
> -5.40299999997373 [ 0.9379999999913338, 0.9070000000145342 ]
> -5.4159999999728825 [ 0.9359999999910542, 0.904000000015003 ]
> -5.428999999972035 [ 0.9339999999907747, 0.9010000000154719 ]
> -5.441999999971188 [ 0.9319999999904951, 0.8980000000159407 ]
> -5.45499999997034 [ 0.9299999999902155, 0.8950000000164096 ]
> -5.467999999969493 [ 0.927999999989936, 0.8920000000168784 ]
> -5.480999999968645 [ 0.9259999999896564, 0.8890000000173472 ]
> -5.493999999967798 [ 0.9239999999893769, 0.8860000000178161 ]
> -5.5069999999669506 [ 0.9219999999890973, 0.8830000000182849 ]
> -5.519999999966103 [ 0.9199999999888178, 0.8800000000187538 ]
> -5.532999999965256 [ 0.9179999999885382, 0.8770000000192226 ]
> -5.545999999964408 [ 0.9159999999882587, 0.8740000000196915 ]
> -5.558999999963561 [ 0.9139999999879791, 0.8710000000201603 ]
> -5.5719999999627134 [ 0.9119999999876995, 0.8680000000206292 ]
> -5.584999999961866 [ 0.90999999998742, 0.865000000021098 ]
> -5.597999999961019 [ 0.9079999999871404, 0.8620000000215668 ]
> -5.610999999960171 [ 0.9059999999868609, 0.8590000000220357 ]
> -5.623999999959324 [ 0.9039999999865813, 0.8560000000225045 ]
> -5.636999999958476 [ 0.9019999999863018, 0.8530000000229734 ]
> -5.649999999957629 [ 0.8999999999860222, 0.8500000000234422 ]
```

My question is: isn't it the gradient that tells where to go to minimize the function? If such is the case, then why the solution is drifting away? Thanks for your time and any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Gradient descent finds minima, not zeros. Note that your function attains values that are smaller than zero. It actually diverges to minus infinity, so that's what your gradient descent does.

Comment: Little confused. Are you minimizing a linear function?

Comment: A descent method will attempt to decrease the cost. Since you have a linear objective which is unbounded below and a fixed step size, this approach should produce a set of points that lie on a line 'go to infinity'.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to minimize this linear function. My assumption was that it should achieve minimal values by the gradient descent and then gradients will indicate the bound of where to stop or if to proceed or not. So, if I want to employ this strategy, what is the change that might be done?

Comment: @copper.hat : so, should the cost function be wrapped around the objective function to achieve this? I am kind of confused on how to move forward with this? Suppose we have a linear function like this and we want to achieve optimal values..what should be the procedure then?

Comment: A linear function on an unconstrained domain is unbounded below, there is nothing you can do about that. I don't understand the difference between cost and objective.

Comment: Think of minimising $x \mapsto x$ over the real line. It has no minimum value, because you can always find a smaller value.